Plotly Image ignores alpha channel
I'm attempting to display a (semi) transparent image using plotly's go.Image object. I use cv2 to load the image from disk and convert it to rgba format. Following this issue, I manually set colormodel='rgba' but the resulting image still ignores the alpha value.
Example code:
import cv2
import plotly.graph_objects as go

original = cv2.imread(<path_to_image>)
original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

transparent = cv2.cvtColor(original , cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
transparent[:, :, 3] = 127    # set to 255 // 2 for half-transparency

fig1 = go.Figure(go.Image(z=original))
fig1.show()

fig2 = go.Figure(go.Image(z=img2, colormodel='rgba'))
fig2.show()

Both fig1 and fig2 present the same image, but fig2 displays 4-channel pixels:

Seems like plotly cannot display transparent images. Is there a way to display the image with the alpha channel?

If an alpha value of 256 bytes is specified, the color model will be 'rgba256'.
The 'colormodel' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
One of the following enumeration values:['rgb', 'rgba', 'rgba256', 'hsl', 'hsla']

Great, I messed up reading the docs :(
Write this as an answer and I'll upvote it, @r-beginners
